# hx-swap-oob creates duplicate dom element?

Tags: django, swap, htmx

I have this workflow:

1. new record is being inserted in database
2. using HTMX, the row inserted should show up in table (the whole table gets reRendered)
3. simuoultaneously with previous step, certain number should show up in a paragraph element (paragraph gets reRendered).

I've tried to accomplish this using `hx-swap-oob="true"` argument on a paragraph element but the problem is that DOM element (paragraph) is being duplicated for some reason. Can someone tell me why is this happening and how to solve this?

## Template.html

```
<table class="ui celled table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody hx-post="{% url 'books' book.id %}" hx-trigger="addBook from:body" hx-vals='{"action": "show_editions"}' id="book_list">
        {% include "selling-books.html" %}
    </tbody>
</table>
...
... # some other DOM elements
...
<p id="book_number">{{ book.number }}</p>
```

## Selling-books.html

```
{% for edition in editions %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ edition.in }} pieces</td>
    <td>{{ edition.out }} pieces</td>
    <td>{{ edition.price }} USD</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

<p hx-swap-oob="true" id="book_number">{{ book.number }}</p>
```

## Views.py

```
def book_status(request, template_name = 'book.html', id=""):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    editions = Edition.objects.filter(book_id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
            action = request.POST.get('action')
            
            if action == 'addBook':
                addEdition_form = AddBookForm(request.POST or None)
                if addEdition_form.is_valid():
                    ... some logic ...
                    
                    return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Trigger': 'addBook'})

            if action == 'show_editions':
                for edition in editions:
                    ... some logic ...
                return render(request, 'selling-book.html', {'editions': editions, 'book': book})
    
    else:
        return render(request, template_name, {'book':book, 'editions':editions, 'addEdition_form': addEdition_form})
```

Comment: Makes sense, since you're re-using the template and so the internal <p> is shown as well. You can avoid it by checking if the `addEdition_form` variable exists in the template for example. If it does then don't show the internal <p> (or you can define and pass your own context value)

Comment: I have seen `<tr>` values confuse htmx-swap-oob's place in the DOM. Try placing the `<p>` at the head of the selling-books.html include.

Comment: @mariodev Thanks for the suggestion, but then it looks like I don't know how htmx-swab-oob is supposed to work. I thought that it just replaces the existing element in the DOM and that it would not render a new identical element.
**Anyhow, this hack solves my problem, thanks for that!**
I'm trying to combine all the logic in a single view (using template partials) and I suppose that there must be a more elegant way to accomplish this without cheating :) Please, don't think that I'm ungrateful, I'm just trying to learn htmx (+ django) the proper way..

Comment: @SamSparx Yeah, that was my thinking also, so I tried to place <p> at the head, but that didn't help either.
Also, I've included `<meta name="htmx-config" content='{"useTemplateFragments":"true"}'>` in my base template.

Comment: @LjubisaLivac I see your point, the other solution could be to split the templates (eg  `Selling-books-table.html`), using it only for rendering <tr> part and then use `Selling-books.html` which includes the table template and use it to render it seperately. Any other solution will likely require js, the OOB swap will never be elegant enough I feel like ;)..

Comment: @mariodev Thanks for the clarification! If you wish, answer to my question (with the first comment) and I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the duplicate by checking if the `addEdition_form` variable exists in your template.

Altervative solution may be to split the table content and counter paragraph into seperate templates.